# openid general authorization error when trying to log from mobile app

Tags: mobile, error-handling, authorization, openid

I am getting this openid authernisation error when trying to log into an openid service from a mobile app, could anyone explain to me the possible causes?

> Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.general Code=-4

In the documentation it says "general" error, wouldbe good to have more insight on what are the potential causes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It is authorisation error and in my case was caused by not setting clientSecret with the request.